# how to read JSON file's values in freemarker(ftl) file?

Tags: json, freemarker

i have to read a json file which contains the property values in another ftl file. I have tried reading by assigning as

```
<#assign values="/etc/templates/property.json">
```

and then try to use the attributes in the values, but it is assigning values a string value instead of reading value from assigned path.
What should i do to read values from the property.json file?

Answer (score 2):

This is out of scope for FreeMarker itself. It's always used as part of some higher level framework, and that should provide such functionality, or expose the file content in the data-model. (Especially templates loading from absolute paths is quite atypical.)